# No me crea el objeto const phoneNumber = getPhoneNumberFromUserInput() ni const code = getCodeFromUserInput() en firebase

Tags: firebase

Hola tengo importadas estas librerías de firebase, incluidas las de firebaseui, en mi caso el captcha si me lo pinta y funciona correctemente, pero no me pinta ni el imput del teléfono ni el de el código, estoy utilizando la autentificación dentro de un infoWindow de un map de google, las librerias que tengo importadas son las siguientes.

```
<!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
  <!-- Firebase App is always required and must be first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.1/firebase-functions.js"></script> 
 <!-- Comment out (or don't include) services that you don't want to use -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.1/firebase-storage.js"></script> 
  
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.4.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.4.0/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.4.0/firebase-ui-auth__es.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.4.0/firebase-ui-auth.css" />


<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.css" />
 
//El trozo de código donde los recoge:

    const phoneNumber = getPhoneNumberFromUserInput();
         
         firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
         .then((confirmationResult) => {
           // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
           // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code)
           window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
             const code = getCodeFromUserInput();
         
         confirmationResult.confirm(code).then((result) => {
            // User signed in successfully.
          
           return result.user;
          }).catch((error) => {
            return "nook"
          });

         }).catch((error) => {
           alertify.error("Code no sent");
         });
```